# Server newbie trying to set up spacewalk. I don't know what I'm getting wrong with iptables

Tags: centos, iptables, spacewalk

So I'm trying to setup a spacewalk server on centos 6.8 but it keeps on hanging up on restarting services to install cobbler. It'll just keep going and going without ever making any progress. Finally I changed my iptables policies for input and output to accept, and the installation process finally finished succesfully. But I'm not happy with that. I want to be able to successfully install spacewalk without having to accept all connections, except for those truly necessary for spacewalk to work. Keep in mind I am a complete newbie to servers and to iptables in general, so I'm sorry for the messy policies :(

These are my policies:

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 69 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5269 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5222 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 69 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

EDIT: TLDR I needed to open connections for the loop back interface

For anyone who ever has the same problem:
I added the ports Diogenes made me aware of for cobbler. Unfortunately that didn't fix the problem. As per his second suggestion, I tried to install with the non-working iptables configuration and used "netstat -aln" and saved it to a file. Then I changed the policies to ACCEPT and successfully installed spacewalk and ran netstat again. Then I took the two files and compared them and found that the problem was that 127.0.0.1 wasn't communicating properly. As soon as I added the interface to iptables, spacewalk installed succesfully with the iptable configuration that I wanted (including the default DROP policies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Cobbler requires ports 25150 and 25151. From the Reference Guide for Cobbler, [Section 11.1.1 (Using Cobbler check)](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Network_Satellite/5.3/html/Reference_Guide/ch-cobbler.html#s2-cobbler-reqs-check):

> iptables — Will remind you that if you are running an IPTables
>   firewall, that you have rules set to allow ports 69 (TFTP), 80
>   (HTTPD), 25150 and 25151 (Cobbler).
>
> Run the cobbler check command as root on your system to see what
>   settings and services need to be enabled to properly run Cobbler on
>   your boot server.

With your firewall rules temporarily disabled, you can use netstat -aln or lsof -i to list ports that have attached listeners. That might show you other ports that need to be open for the services you're running.

Comment: I will post an update on the solution later, but your advice led me to the solution. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Great...glad it helped!